# Enable session tracking with jsessionid cookie

Tags: jetty

I wrote some servlets and deployed them on Jetty. However, I discovered that Jetty does not automatically send the JSESSIONID cookie when my servlets are accessed. Instead of setting the cookie manually in the servlet response, is there a ways to enable session tracking with cookies when deploying servlets.

I am using Jetty 11.0.2.

Comment: Not enough information.  How are you starting Jetty? (show details)  How are you using HttpSession? (show code)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that that Jetty sets the `JSESSIONID` cookie when `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` is called. If the function has not been called, no `JSESSIONID` cookie will be set automatically.